# What is workable VS Code configuration to debug Django custom commands?

Tags: django, debugging, configuration, visual-studio-code, command

I am using Visual Studio Code IDE to develop, debug my Django project. I have few management custom commands and don't know how to debug that code from VS Code.
I have tried different configurations but none works.

Configuration I have tried is

```
        {
            "name": "Python: Module",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/manage.py",
            "args": [
                "send_daily",              
            ],
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        },
```

This configuration not stopping at breakpoints I have setup.

I expect the debugger starts and execution stops at the break points setup in the custom command code.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may need to add 'django': true as a field to the config like this example for debugging the migration management command:

```
            "name": "Debug Django Migration",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/manage.py",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "args": [
                "migrate",
            ],
            "django": true
        },
```

Info about the django field https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_django